# Installing mplayer in Linux

Tags: linux, opensuse, software-installation

I don't know if this is the right forum to ask, I have started to use Linux (OpenSUSE). I need to install `mplayer` on it.  I unpacked the mplayer archive.  Then in the command screen I navigated to the folder containing the unpacked folder of mplayer. Then I used the following commands

```
./configure
```

but after that when I entered the `make` command it is showing ...typo doesn't exist or so... I think only after `make` and `make install` I can install this program to my system... please help.

Comment: What does “typo doesnt exist” mean? Always copy-paste complete error messages.

Comment: you are looking for possibly http://www.jeffman.com/kb/entry/69/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was about to say the same thing as @geekosaur, but noticed in the comments that you don't have internet connection on that PC. In general, on Linux software is divided into packages (`mplayer`, `sudo`, `zypper` are examples of packages). Packages are stored in [repositories](http://en.opensuse.org/Package_repositories) and have dependencies on other packages. To save you the task of managing them, there are package managers, such as `zypper`.

You don't normally install software from source, but use the package manager that comes with your system. Now the big problem is that you don't have internet connection on the computer that you want to install software on. If possible, it's a lot easier to plug the cable in and let `zypper` download what it needs. If that's not possible, most package managers have the ability to install from a local repository.

I'm not a SUSE user, but from the [documentation](http://en.opensuse.org/SDB%3aZypper_usage#Adding_repositories) you can download the required .rpm files to make a local repository, then tell `zypper` about it:

```
# zypper ar my/dir/with/rpms local
```

After that you can install `mplayer` without internet connection:

```
# zypper install mplayer
```

If `zypper` then tells you that it needs to install other packages as dependencies (and it will fail because there is no internet connection), you will have to look for the RPM files it need, download and put them in `my/dir/with/rpms` (BTW that's a fake path, change it to whatever path you store the files).

Comment: Upvoted, excellent explanation of package management in general and how zypper works in particular. I'm more of a Debian guy myself, so I don't have any experience with it.

Comment: The interesting question here is, can you get the package manager to tell you (on a system without internet access) what packages need to be downloaded? This can be done with `apt-get` using the `-s` option. Hmm, this might be relevant - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961504/validating-a-yum-repository-for-dependencies

Answer (score 3):

You'd probably be better served by

```
$ sudo zypper install mplayer
```

If you really want to compile from source, you'll need to install a compiler and toolchain.

```
$ sudo zypper install -t devel_C_C++
```

You will also need to install various development library packages; which ones depend on the version of `mplayer` and what features you want to use.  In general, you're better off with the pre-built one; `mplayer` is an absolute beast to build.

Comment: sir i am absolute beginner to this,do i require internet for these commmands,last time i wer trying $sudo install make ...it wer trying to connect to internet?

Comment: Well, yes - zypper is a package manager. When ordered to install software, it checks its list of available package archives for the package name you asked for, then downloads and installs the latest version of the package available in the repositories it knows about.

Comment: @sujith Put more bluntly, it's generally better to not try to install/compile software from source until you've learned your way around linux a bit more so that if/when you break something, you have a chance of knowing what you broke, why it broke and hopefully how to fix it.

Comment: @shadur ok i agree..but this is important for me.... i dont have connectivity with the linux pc and i need to install this mplayer somehow....is there any other way to install that doesnt require internet connectivity  or can i download the make tool from this pc and use it in linux pc

Comment: @sujith In that case you'd be better served manually downloading the package for your distro instead and installing it that way.

Answer (score 1):

For installing SMPlayer in Linux, you need to do the following:

- First, you have to download the .deb package.
- Then install .deb package using the command given below:

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i smplayer_0.5.0_i386.deb
  ```
- Now, you may need to install `libqt4-gui`, `libqt4-core`, etc. You can install them using the following command:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install -f
  ```

This will complete your installation process.For further more details, you can visit the following link: http://www.smplayerdownload.com

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good way to go - [yumdownloader](http://linux.die.net/man/1/yumdownloader). This is part of the `yum-utils` package, which is available on OpenSUSE.

So you might be able to use something like this on your machine to get a list of the urls you need to download from:

```
yumdownloader --urls --resolve mplayer
```

I'm not sure from the (sparse) documentation whether `--resolve` and `--urls` can be used together, and I don't use RH based systems, so can't easily check.